# What is the description of Varanasi in scriptures?

Tags: scripture, kashi

I'm informed that real Kasi/Varanasi is different.  I want to know the description of Varanasi mentioned in scriptures.

Comment: You mean the description of its location, or what?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan How it looks like. What's there in Kashi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Vishvanatha and Varanasi**
>
> The seventh of the jyotirlingas is named
>   Vishvanatha and it is located in the cityof
>   Varanasi or Kashi.
>   Varanasi is a very sacred place. Brahma
>   himself performed difficult tapasya there. So
>   difficult was the tapasya that Vishnu shook
>   his head in disbelief. When Vishnu shook his
>   head, a jewel (mani) fell down from Vishnu’
>   ear (karna). The place where the jewel fall is
>   known as Manikarnika and it is a famous
>   tirtha.
>   Varanasi is not destroyed when the rest of
>   the world is destroyed. Shiva himself raises it
>   on the point of his trident and protects it
>   while destruction rages all around. When the
>   world is re-created. Shiva replaces Varanasi
>   to its appointed place.
>   Shiva and Parvati once went to visit Brahma.
>   Brahma began to chant hymns in Shiva’s
>   praise with all of his five mouths. One of the
>   mouths however made mistakes in the
>   pronunciation of the hymns. This angered
>   Shiva and Shiva severed the offending head
>   with a gaze of his third eye. But this
>   effectively amounted to the killing of a
>   brahmana and Shiva committed a crime. The
>   severed head therefore got stuck to Shiva’s
>   back would would not come off, no matter
>   where Siva went. But when Shiva arrived in
>   Varanasi, the head fell off his back. Shiva
>   realized that Varanasi was a special place
>   and he resolved that he would always be
>   present there.
>
> —Shiva purana:chapter25

source:— http://www.bharatadesam.com/spiritual/shiva_purana.php

> **The City of Varanasi**
>
> The city of Varanasi is very sacred. Shiva
>   himself lived here with Parvati and Ganesha.
>   Varanasi is one of the six greatest tirthas on
>   earth. The other five are Kurukshetra,
>   Shriparvata, Mahalaya, Tungeshvara and
>   Kedara.
>   The sins of someone who worships Shiva in
>   Varanasi are immediately forgiven. Any living
>   being who dies in the city goes immediately
>   to heaven. Several are the lingas and sacred
>   ponds in Varanasi; some of them were set up
>   by Vishnu and Brahma themselves.
>   The river Varuna winds through the city and
>   unites with the holy river Ganga. At the
>   confluence of the Varuna and the Ganga,
>   Brahma established a linga known as
>   Sangameshvara. Amongst other famous
>   lingas in Varanasi are Shailesha, Svarnilesha,
>   Madhyameshvara, Hiranyagarbheshvara,
>   Goprekshaka, Vrishadhvaja, Upashantashiva,
>   Shukreshvara, Vyaghreshvara and
>   Jambukeshvara.
>
> —Linga purana:chapter16

source:— http://www.bharatadesam.com/spiritual/linga_purana.php

**NOTE:—ORIGINAL CHAPTER NO. MAY VARY**